# Размер загружаемого изображения

Tags: django

Не получается сделать проверку, почему-то выдает ошибку nginx:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

models.py

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def file_size(value):
    limit = 5 * 1024 * 1024
    if value.size > limit:
        raise ValidationError('Размер файла не должен превышать 5 mb.')

class News(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(
        validators=[file_size],
        blank=True,
)
```

forms.py

```
class NewsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = News
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: [Видимо на nginx стоит свое ограничение?](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size)

Comment: [тут примеры как перенастроить](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476643/default-nginx-client-max-body-size)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Да, на nginx стояло ограничение